# How do I enable all options in the context menu of a QDialog?

Tags: qt, qdialog

How do I enable all options in the context menu of a QDialog? (Minimize and maximize). I only find help about enabling the window flags, but that's not really necessary.

[image: Dialog menu]

Comment: Why do you say that flags are not helping? If you set the flag `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint`, it will show you Minimize and maximize in the context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum), Qt::Dialog flag deactivates Minimize/Maximize options.

To enable it, you need to change window flags using the method:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
```

What's more, if you want to be able to minimize your dialog box alone you need to add these methods:

```
setParent(NULL);
setWindowModality(Qt::NonModal);
```

In fact, your QDialog becomes a QWindow.

Comment: Helpful answer. My window was already NonModal. In python the line reads "myapp.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinMaxButtonsHint)"