# how to make working minimize button action in Qdialog

Tags: python, pyqt5

now i make Some application using PYQT5.

i want minimize my app , when button clicked that you can see under the picture.

how to i make minimize button or how to action minimize.

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Please provide a minimum example which reproduces your issue: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How did you create that window shown in the picture? Is it a dialogue (because we see a window in the background)?

Answer (score 1):

For QDialog there are options under setWindowsFlag where you can set whether the minimize and maximize button to be visible or hidden. By default they are set to be hidden.

```
dialog.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint, True)
dialog.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint, True)
```

for minimizing and maximizing respectively

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** The OS or platform's windowing-system is responsible of drawing the window-icons/-buttons as well as primary event-handling for actions "minimize", "maximize", etc. Some QtWidgets like `QDialog` have predefined window-flags. The desired window-buttons can be set using `widget.setWindowFlag(flags | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)`

### Drawing Windows (incl. Dialogues) in Qt

Note: The recommended way of drawing windows is using [`QtWidget`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qwidget.html) or `QQuickWindow`.

See [QWindow — PyQt v5.15 Reference Guide](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtgui/qwindow.html?highlight=minimize#description), description:

> The `QWindow` class represents a window **in the underlying *windowing system***.
>
> A window that is supplied a parent becomes a native child window of their parent window.
>
> An application will **typically use `QWidget` or `QQuickView`** for its UI, and not `QWindow` directly. Still,

(formatting and emphasize mine)

Search the docs in PyQt for "minimized".
Like [`QWindow`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtgui/qwindow.html?highlight=minimize) the [`QtWidget`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qwidget.html?highlight=minimize), which [`QDialog`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qdialog.html?highlight=minimize) inherits from, has several event-handling methods supporting `minimized` state:

- `minimized` property
- `showMinimized()` function

But no explicit method or property to draw this window-button for the Window action "minimize".

#### Windowing-System responsibility

The appearance and rendering, as well as modifier-buttons shown in the window-edges depends on the Platform/OS and [*windowing-system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system) (like e.g. Linux's [X-Window system X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) and deployed [window-manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager)).

### Using Qt's `WindowFlags`

[Window Flags Example | Qt Widgets 5.15.7](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html):

> A widget's flags are stored in a Qt::WindowFlags type which stores an OR combination of the flags.

In PyQt this is implemented using the class `QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags` which is a set of the [`QtCore.Qt.WindowType`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtcore/qt.html#WindowType) enum:

> The `CustomizeWindowHint` flag is used to enable customization of the window controls. This flag must be set to allow the `WindowTitleHint`, `WindowSystemMenuHint`, `WindowMinimizeButtonHint`, `WindowMaximizeButtonHint` and `WindowCloseButtonHint` flags to be changed.

These methods of  `QWindow` support `WindowFlags`:

- `flags() → WindowFlags`
- `setFlags(Union[WindowFlags, WindowType])`

And, these methods of `QWidget` support `WindowFlags`:

- `__init__(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[WindowFlags, WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags())`
- `windowFlags() → WindowFlags`
- `setWindowFlags(Union[WindowFlags, WindowType])`
- `overrideWindowFlags(Union[WindowFlags, WindowType])`

Example:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt # WindowFlags, WindowType

window = QQuickWindow(flags=Qt.WindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint))
print('current window-flags, represented as int:', window.flags(), int(window.flags()) )
window.setFlags(Qt.WindowFlags(Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint))
```

Prints:

> current window-flags, represented as int: <PyQt5.QtCore.WindowFlags object at 0x7fc471d574a8> **16384**

Showing the `int` representation of `WindowFalgs` instance.

Draws: [image: QQuickWindow with unset WindowMinimizeButtonHint]

### QDialog, default window-flags and how to modify

Dialogs are special type of window. They often are not resizable, can not be minimized or maximized. Sometimes they are bound to the parent-window (see also *Modal dialogues*).

`QDialog` for example has some default flags.

> The widget flags `f` are passed on to the `QWidget` constructor. If, for example, you don't want a *What's This* button in the title bar of the dialog, pass `Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint` in `f`.

#### How to query and modify window-flags on QWidgets like QDialog

Example for PyQt's [`QDialog`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qdialog.html) where `MinimizeWindowButtonHint` is set:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt # WindowFlags, WindowType

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QDialog()
widget.setWindowTitle('QDialog demo')
print('current dialog-flags, represented as int and hex:', widget.windowFlags(), int(widget.windowFlags()), hex(int(widget.windowFlags())) )

widget.setWindowFlags(widget.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
print('after added min&max then dialog-flags, represented as int and hex:', widget.windowFlags(), int(widget.windowFlags()), hex(int(widget.windowFlags())) )

widget.resize(400,100)
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Renders (on Linux/Ubuntu using XFCE windowing-system):
[image: QDialgou with explicitly set WindowFlags()]

Prints:

> current dialog-flags, represented as int and hex: <PyQt5.QtCore.WindowFlags object at 0x7fc6509d10b8> 134295555 **0x8013003**
>
> after added min&max then dialog-flags, represented as int and hex: <PyQt5.QtCore.WindowFlags object at 0x7fc6509d1198> 134344707 **0x801f003**

### Working with WindowFlags and their combinations

However, the first are the default window-flags for `QDialogue` because the class is inherited from QWidget and [`QWidget.windowFlags` are predefined too](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop):

> Window flags are a **combination of** a *type* (e.g. [`Qt::Dialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)) and zero or more *hints* to the *window system* (e.g. [`Qt::FramelessWindowHint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)).

If we convert the decimal value of QDialog's default flags [`134295554` from decimal to hex](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html?x=134295554) we get:
`8013002` as hex, in programming languages also written as `0x8013002`.

Compare this to [Qt's WindowType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

| enum constant | hex value | default of QDialog |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Qt::Window | `0x00000001` | No |
| **Qt::Dialog** | `0x00000002 | Window` | Yes |
| **Qt::WindowTitleHint** | `0x00001000` | Yes |
| **Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint** | `0x00002000` | Yes |
| Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | `0x00004000` | No |
| Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | `0x00008000` | No |
| Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint | `WindowMinimizeButtonHint | WindowMaximizeButtonHint` | No |
| **Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint** | `0x00010000` | Yes |
| **Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint** | `0x08000000` | Yes |

When adding all above **marked in bold** (with last column "Yes") added into one set of flags using boolean OR `|`, we get:
`0x8013002` as default-flags for `QDialog`.

After printing the initial flags, we **added** both `WindowMinimizeButtonHint` and `WindowMaximizeButtonHint` using boolean OR:
`widget.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint`

So the dialog now has existing QDialog's default-flags (window-buttons) plus additional minimize & maximize buttons.

### See also

- [Can't add minimize button to QDialog under linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699808/cant-add-minimize-button-to-qdialog-under-linux)
- [How do I enable all options in the context menu of a QDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066095/how-do-i-enable-all-options-in-the-context-menu-of-a-qdialog)
- [How to make a custom minimize button in pyqt5 QDialog after setting FramelessWindowHint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550200/how-to-make-a-custom-minimize-button-in-pyqt5-qdialog-after-setting-framelesswin)
- [QDialog remove title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181630/qdialog-remove-title-bar)